# Pass variable forbidden because of htaccess file

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

This is my second post because i also can't find the solution so I am looking forward to your help. My company website has been created by a resigned staff. He used the htaccess file to exchange all of the link in website. And now, when I want to pass a variable from one page to second page via address bar, the second page can't GET the variable because of the affect of htaccess. Anyone can help me to find the solution to revise the htaccess when i had tiny experience of htaccess file. Here is htacess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options All -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ index.php
RewriteRule ^B2C/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?lang=$1&p=$2&id=$3
RewriteRule ^B2C/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?lang=$1&p=$2
RewriteRule ^B2C/(.*)/$ index.php?lang=$1
RewriteRule ^postoffice.html$ more/PO.php
RewriteRule ^hospital-clinic.html$ more/HO.php
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/401.html
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.html

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
```

Here is my code in tag  which want to pass the variable $main_po_num in page "1"

```
echo "<td><a href='B2C/$lang/Contact_detail.html?abc=$main_po_num'>$main_po_num</a></td>";
```

Here is code I vardump in page "2" which return NULL (meaning can't Get the pass variable)

```
var_dump ($_GET["abc"]);
```

Even the address bar can display the variable

> .64.4:1234/B2C/vi/Customer_Contact?abc=S110023845.html

So how can i revise the htacess then i can pass and get the variable between 2 page. THANKS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^B2C/(.*)/$ index.php?lang=$1 [QSA]
```

The `[QSA]` flag appends the query string (in your case, `abc`) to this rule. Currently, your rule ignores the query string that was passed and uses only the `lang`, etc. variables. For this to apply to all of your rules, each rule needs this flag at the end.

From the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> Modifying the Query String
>
> By default, the query string is passed through unchanged. You can,
>   however, create URLs in the substitution string containing a query
>   string part. Simply use a question mark inside the substitution string
>   to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into the
>   query string. When you want to erase an existing query string, end the
>   substitution string with just a question mark. **To combine new and old
>   query strings, use the [QSA] flag.**

Answer (score 4):

Add to the end of all rewriterules a [[qsa]](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa).

That will add the get variables.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Your mean is write ---a [qsa]--- or only ---[qsa]--- or  ---rewriterules a [qsa]--- in the bottom of Rewriterule.

Comment: See Evan Mulawski's answer. It's a little hard to write in the car.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with htaccess in a little while so this is just a fairly educated guess but you can give it a try.

This line:

```
RewriteRule ^B2C/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?lang=$1&p=$2
```

is working on your example:

```
<a href='B2C/$lang/Contact_detail.html?abc=$main_po_num'>$main_po_num</a>;
```

Essentially what's happening is the first (.*) is getting rewritten to be inserted into $1 and the second (.*) is getting substituted into $2.

So, again I'm not 100% this is the correct syntax so you might have to look this up, but you should be able to do something like:

```
RewriteRule ^B2C/(.*)/(.*).html/?(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&p=$2&$3
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. But it's work for me when i walk to add QSA flag. However, thanks for your explaining which can help me more understanding about htacess fiile